# DataJPATest attempts to load everything

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have my application, with a lot of components.
I'd like to test my queries so I annotated my tests with:

```
@DataJPATest
```

Problem is that it also tries to load every single bean!
What am I missing?

Comment: If you have more annotations/config on/in your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class that will be included. Solution move that to a seperate `@Configuration` class.

Comment: yes I have a lot...but they are in separate @configuration, can't udestand what you mean

Comment: Please add your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class as well as your test class to your question.